# Разрешения на звонки

Tags: android, unity3d, android-sdk, unity3d-android

Вскрыв свое приложения, посмотрев манифест, я увидел что мои разрешения следующие:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Test.MyT"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:banner="@drawable/app_banner"
    android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
    android:isGame="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
    <activity
        android:name="com.Test.MyT.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
            android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="net.agasper.unitynotification.UnityNotificationManager"></receiver>
    <receiver android:name="net.agasper.unitynotification.UnityNotificationActionHandler"></receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.build-id"
        android:value="37398183-4f58-476f-b4d6-f7a87b9ae80b" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-mode"
        android:value="0" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-enable"
        android:value="True" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
    android:required="false" />
```

Но почему-то на телефоне, пишет что нужно еще какие-то разрешения (камера нужна, остальное нет)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот разрешения с adb

```
    uses-permission: android.permission.CAMERA
    uses-permission: android.permission.VIBRATE
    uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
```

Comment: Покажи весь манифест, без вырезок.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev обновил

Comment: Очень странно. Какая версия android? может вы не тот файл распаковываете и не там смотрите? есть возможность подключить смартфон к ПК и посмотреть разрешения у приложения через `adb`?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev подключил, так же написанно.обновил вопрос (добавил с adb)

Comment: Что значит вскрыв!? Вы какие используете библиотеки или модули? Когда открываете манифест в студии, в низу экрана есть вкладка: MergedManifest. Внимательно посмотрите там. Вы там скорее всего найдёте не только ответ на свой вопрос, но и источник.

Comment: @Valeriy написано приложения на юнити, там нет такого, там несколько манифестов скрещиваються. Но взяв основной апк файл и достав из него манифест, я увидел то что написал выше.